# How can I use File.AppendAllText and add to it a new line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public static void Save(string saveString)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + "savegame.txt", saveString);
    }
```

The method is being called twice or even more times and each time with another saveString.
The content of the saved file is like this :

```
{"objects":[{"Key":"367f6ac2-6fd3-4c99-91e5-cc335a104ac4","Value":"{\"s1\":false}"}],"instanceID":0,"position":{"x":8.140000343322754,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"scaling":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0,"z":1.0},"rotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0}}{"objects":[{"Key":"ecb45f8e-463c-4fe3-a436-5d836165bcce","Value":"{\"s1\":false}"}],"instanceID":0,"position":{"x":-11.229999542236329,"y":0.0,"z":8.920000076293946},"scaling":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0,"z":1.0},"rotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0}}
```

And I want to format it to something nicer to be easier to look at maybe adding an empty line between each string ? Or some other format ?

This is how I'm saving it with json :

```
public void Save()
    {
        SaveObject saveObject = new SaveObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToSave.Count; i++)
        {
            var x = objectsToSave[i].GetComponents<Component>();
            var y = x.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
            List<KeyToValue> myObjects = new List<KeyToValue>();
            foreach(var z in y)
            {
                var w = z as IStateQuery;
                myObjects.Add(new KeyToValue(w.UniqueId.ToString(), w.GetState()));
                
            }
            saveObject.position = objectsToSave[i].position;
            saveObject.scaling = objectsToSave[i].localScale;
            saveObject.rotation = objectsToSave[i].rotation;

            saveObject.objects = myObjects;


            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveObject);

            SaveSystem.Save(json);
        }
    }
```

But I don't like the format of the content in the file.

I tried to add Environment.NewLine :

```
File.AppendAllText(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + "savegame.txt" + Environment.NewLine, saveString);
```

But it's giving me error :

ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your fix might be as simple as this:

```
File.AppendAllText(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + "savegame.txt" , Environment.NewLine + saveString);
// or even better at the end
File.AppendAllText(SAVE_FOLDER + "/" + "savegame.txt" ,  saveString + Environment.NewLine);
```

You are adding the new line to the filename and it is indeed invalid. Add it before or after your content and you'll do fine.

By the way, the content of the file, is not a valid json. While each line is, the total file is not as the following syntax is invalid

```
{}
{}
```

If you want it all to be a JSon object you'll need something like this

```
[
   {},
   {}
]
```

Comment: I thought the json format it automatic when using it.  I need to format the string on my own to get the json valid syntax ?

Comment: Each individual row, is of proper json format as you assumed. The total file is not. You might not even need it to be. If you do need to load all save games into an array, if you leave it this way, you'll need to deserialize each row and then add to the array.

Comment: Anyway, was your problem solved solved? If it was, please mark this answer as correct and start a new one asking how to make a proper json.

Comment: I found that I need to add twice the Environment.NewLine at your solution then it's adding an empty line. but it also adding empty line to the end at the bottom. How can I avoid from it to add empty line at the end bottom ?